# Are "crontab -e" & "/etc/crontab" the same?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, debian

I'm wondering if it matters if I add a crontab to `/etc/crontab` or `crontab -e`?

I have an Ubuntu 17 and Debian 9 VM running, and I'm confused which one is the right place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same.

The `crontab` command is specific to a user.  When you edit your
crontab (via `crontab -e`) you are really saving it to
`/var/spool/cron/`.  I find this to be more geared toward interactive
setup/maintenance: it uses your `$EDITOR`.  (Though I have seen tools
like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that will
automatically populate a user crontab.

The "system" cron files live in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d`.
These are similar to your user's crontab, but the format has an
additional (sixth) field to specify which user to run as, and you'll
need root privileges to change these.  The latter directory is often
used by tools to place a cron script into, by system installs, or your
own deployment routines.

You'll also find related system directories in `/etc/`, such as
`cron.daily/`, `cron.hourly/`, etc.  These hold normal scripts that are
run on their respective cadence.  E.g., `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`
rotates system log files daily.  They typically orchestrated by your
`/etc/anacrontab` to add some small random delay across systems.

There are a few places to look for documentation of the various pieces
of cron.  The relevant man pages are:

```
crontab(1) -- the command
crontab(5) -- spec formatting
cron(8) -- the daemon
```

An alternative to cron with SystemD now is
[timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#As_a_cron_replacement).